# Advantages of Activiti

Tags: jbpm, activiti, bpmn

I have gone through few threads which discuss about jBPM5 vs Activiti. New features have been added in jBPM6. what are the advantage of using activiti ..in which case activiti is suitable

Comment: This post will probably help you ;) - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279329/bonitasoft-bpm-vs-jbpm-vs-activiti

Comment: Mentioned thread compares features of jbpm5 vs activiti.. Some of the..I have also gone through activiti in action..can somebody help me in understanding the key differences

Comment: Hi There, the main differences is that jBPM is fully integrated with the drools project which allows you more flexibility when you realise that with a Business process engine is not enough for automating complex business scenarios. Drools & jBPM are designed together with the main goal of facilitate the authoring and automation of business knowledge in general, not just processes. I suggest you to check out the latest version of our extensible workbench called KIE Workbench.

Comment: What about activiti.. Even activiti supports drools..how about the code in jbpm..does it require Java code to model the business process